# Anonymous containers

Tags: raku

Define a variable `$a`:

```
my $a = 123;
```

Define a sigilless variable associated with `$a`:

```
my \b = $a;
```

We can change the value of `$a` via `b`:

```
b = 234;

say $a;
```

That should display `234`.

My understanding is this works because `b` is set to the container associated with `$a`.

Is there a way to define an anonymous container? I.e. something like this:

```
my \b = container(123);
```

Since `b` is associated with a container, assignment would work as in the first example:

```
b = 234;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `my $` instead of `my $a`.

(Thanks go to @BradGilbert++ for fixing a very basic mistake with the first version of this answer in which I proposed using just `$` instead of `my $`; see comments replying to this answer.)

---

Note that `=`, when used as the operator for initializing a sigil slashed declaration, does [binding](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-Binding_operator) (acts the same as `:=`), *not* [assignment](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-List_assignment_operator).

The following code declares an anonymous `Scalar` container, *assigns* (copies) `123` to it<sup>1</sup>, declares a sigil-slashed symbol `a`, and *binds* `a` to the `Scalar`<sup>1</sup>:

```
my \a = my $ = 123;
#             *Assigns* 123 to an anonymous Scalar
#      *Binds* a to the anonymous Scalar 
say a;                     # 123
a = 234;
say a;                     # 234
```

## Footnote

<sup>1</sup> In the expression `foo = bar` (an assignment) the convention is to say one *assigns* (copies) a *right* hand side value (or variable's value) *to* (into) a left hand variable/container. In the expression `baz := waldo` (a binding) the convention is to say one *binds* the *left* hand side symbol/variable *to* the *right* hand variable/container/value.

Comment: @dharmatech Note that just `$` by itself is the same as `state $`, you may want `my $` instead, particularly if this is in a subroutine. `my \a = my $ = 123;`

Comment: @BradGilbert: Is there a semantic impact? If `my \a = $ = 123` is in a sub, the compiler creates both the `a` variable and the anonymous container the first time that line is encountered. At the end of the sub the `a` variable is thrown to the garbage collector but the anon container isn't. If the same line is encountered again (eg calling the sub again) the `a` variable is regenerated but the anon `$` isn't. The assignments still happen so `a` still  gets `123`. `my \a = my $ = 123` means the anon `$` gets thrown away at the same time as the `a` variable which influences memory use and speed.

Comment: @raiph not if you could be in the subroutine in more than one thread at a time. `sub c (\v){my \a = $ = v; await Promise.in: (1..5).pick; say  "{v} {'!' x (v !eqv a)}eqv {a}"; }; eager (1..5).race(:batch(1)).map: &c`

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a way to assign `b` a container that doesn't have another name in the same scope as `b`:

```
my \b = { my $a = 123; $a; }();

b = 234;

say b;
```

So, going with that approach, `container` can be defined as follows:

```
sub container(\val) is rw { my $var = val; $var; }
```

Example:

```
my \b = container(123);

b = 234;

say b;
```

Displays `234`.

Comment: or much simpler `sub container(\val) is rw { my $ = val }`

Comment: or even `sub container($c is copy) is rw { $c }`